# how can i run certain condition till it becomes false?

Tags: java, android

this is login program in which user enters username and password and is directed to another activity with the toast "login successful" but even if the user enters right username and password, loop runs the toast for 4 times(arrays length), one time it shows "login successful" , other times it shows "login unsuccessful"

i want this program just to show "login successful" once.

how can i run the if part till it becomes false, and then run the else part?

```
String names[] = {"Pa" , "An", "Du", "De"};
String pass[] = {"P", "A", "D", "S"};
String gender[] = {"Female" , "Female" , "Female" , "Male"};


Button button;
EditText n,p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    n = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

    p = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nn = n.getText().toString();
            String pp = p.getText().toString();


            int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

                    if (nn.equals(names[i])) {
                            index = i;

                            if (pp.equals(pass[index])) {


                                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                CharSequence text = "Login Successful!";
                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                toast.show();


                                Intent intent = new Intent(Account.this, MainPage.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                            if (!(pp.equals(pass[index]))) {

                                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                                CharSequence text = "Incorrect Password";

                                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        }


                else {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Incorrect Username!";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    }

                    }

                }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not matter if password matches or not, you need to break the for loop once username is matched

Comment: i have tried that, but then my program doesn't shows the toast when username is entered incorrectly.

Comment: I have posted a answer with a break statement placed at accurate line, please check that

Comment: answer updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a break when username matches and moved else part out of loop

So if all the users in names array are exhausted then it will print `Incorrect Username!`

```
  String names[] = {"Pa", "An", "Du", "De"};
  String pass[] = {"P", "A", "D", "S"};
  String gender[] = {"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male"};


  Button button;
  EditText n, p;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    n = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        String nn = n.getText().toString();
        String pp = p.getText().toString();

        int index = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

          if (nn.equals(names[i])) {
            index = i;

            if (pp.equals(pass[index])) {

              Context context = getApplicationContext();
              CharSequence text = "Login Successful!";
              int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
              toast.show();

              Intent intent = new Intent(Account.this, MainPage.class);
              startActivity(intent);

            }
            if (!(pp.equals(pass[index]))) {

              Context context = getApplicationContext();
              CharSequence text = "Incorrect Password";

              int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
              toast.show();
            }
            break; //add break here
          }

        }
        if (i == names.length) {
          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence text = "Incorrect Username!";
          int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
          toast.show();
        }

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: break can't be added here, else will not be recognized if i add break at this position.

Comment: Thank youu so much. it almost solved the problem :p but it doesn't toast the "username incorrect" message :p because index =0

Comment: check now, if it works, please upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `break` keyword to come out of `for loop` on success

```
if (pp.equals(pass[index])) {
     Context context = getApplicationContext();
     CharSequence text = "Login Successful!";
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
     toast.show();
     Intent intent = new Intent(Account.this, MainPage.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     break;
  }
```

Comment: it works perfect if i enter username and password of index one. if i enter the username or password of index 2/3/4, the loop runs the toast for index 1, saying "Incorrect username" then saying "login successful"

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
Boolean userNameFound = false;
int userNameIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    String expectedName = names[i];
    if (nn.equals(expectedName)) {
        userNameFound = true;
        userNameIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

String message = null;
if (userNameFound) {
    String expectedPassowrd = pass[userNameIndex];
    if (pp.equals(expectedPassowrd)) {
        message = "Login Successful!";
    } else {
        message = "Incorrect Password!";
    }
} else {
    nessage = "Incorrect Username!"
}

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
toast.show();
```